# Splitting of tangent bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, cotangent-bundles

Is it possible to give an example of $n$ dimensional manifold with the property that the tangent bundle $TM$ cannot be expressed as Whitney sum of two subbundles? It is certain true for two sphere; it is certainly not true for three dimensional manifold since every three manifold is parallelizable. You can always split $TM$ as $\gamma \oplus Q$ where $\gamma$ is one dimensional if you can find non vanishing vector field (i.e. where the Euler class is zero which is the case for odd dimension) but what about examples with $n$ even, larger than $2$?

Comment: Spheres of higher even dimensions have non-splittable tangent bundles. This can be shown using Euler classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To expand on my comment above, suppose that $TS^{2k}\cong\xi\oplus\eta$ for some non-trivial vector bundles $\xi$ and $\eta$ over $S^{2k}$ of dimensions $m$ and $\ell$, respectively. Hence $0<m,\ell<2k$. Since $S^{2k}$ is simply-connected, both $\xi$ and $\eta$ are oriented, hence possess Euler classes
$$
e(\xi)\in H^m(S^{2k};\mathbb{Z}),\qquad e(\eta)\in H^{\ell}(S^{2k};\mathbb{Z}).
$$
Since $S^{2k}$ is $(2k-1)$-connected, both are zero.

However, Property 9.6 of Euler classes in Milnor and Stasheff then gives that that
$$e(TS^{2k})=e(\xi)\cup e(\eta)=0.$$
This is a contradiction, since
$$
0\neq 2=\chi(S^{2k}) = \langle e(TS^{2k}),[S^{2k}]\rangle
$$
(this is Corollary 11.12 in Milnor and Stasheff).

Answer (score 7):

I like to play around with projective spaces for these type of questions. The tangent bundles of real projective spaces have stiefel whitney class $(1+a)^{n+1}$. So for example for $n=4$, we have stiefel whitney class $1+a+a^4$. This polynomial is irreducible hence the tangent bundle does not split.

EDIT:

The comment below made me realise I was not clear. If the tangent bundle splitted, let's say $T\mathbb{RP}^4=E\oplus F$, we would find for the stiefel Whitney class that
$$
sw(T\mathbb{RP}^4)=sw(E)sw(F)
$$
But $\dim E+ \dim F=4$ and the right hand side maximally has terms of the form $a^4$. The Stiefel Whitney class $1+a+a^4$ would factor then also in $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]$ (not only in $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/a^5$). It is true that $1+a+a^4$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/a^5$, and in fact stably the tangent bundle does split as $T\mathbb{RP}^4\oplus \mathbb{R}\cong\tau^5$, where $\tau$ is the dual of the tautological bundle.

Comment: Well, it is not irreducible in $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n.\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/a^{n+1}$ because as you notice $1+a+a^4 = (1+a)^{5}$ so, it doesn't seems as valid argument for me. How irreducability in $Z[a]$ helps you to determine irreducability of tangent bundle of projective space?

Comment: @kp9r4d: I added some explanation

Comment: @kp9r4d: You are welcome. Thank you for pointing out my sloppiness.

Answer (score 4):

A condition that prevents a vector bundle from splitting a Whitney sum 
is that the *projection of the associated sphere bundle induces a non-surjective map on some homotopy group*. This is proved by L.Guijarro and G.Walschap in  [Transitive holonomy groups and rigidity in nonnegative curvature](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/lguijarr/papers/transi.pdf) who show that the above condition forces the normal holonomy of the bundle to be transitive (which is clearly impossible if the bundle splits as a Whitney sum).

For example, they explain in the paper that the tangent bundle to $CP^n$ with $n>1$ splits as a Whitney sum if and only if $n$ is odd.

Comment: For the record, when $n$ is odd, $T\mathbb{CP}^n$ splits only into the Whitney sum of a complex line bundle and its complement. See Theorem 1.1 (ii) of Glover, Homer, & Stong's [*Splitting the Tangent Bundle of Projective Space*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24893028).