# Prove a generalization of hairy-ball theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I found an interesting question below:

Prove that the 6-sphere admits no continuous field of tangent 3-planes.

Comment: A 3-plane bundle over $S^6$ would be characterized by an element of $\pi_5(S^3)=\mathbb Z_2$.  If the tangent bundle had a 3-dimensional subbundle, it would decompose as the sum of a pair of 3-plane bundles and therefore be torsion.  But the tangent bundle has characteristic classes of infinite order, contradiction.  I am not posting this as an *answer* because I haven't thought about homotopy groups in a while.  Some topologist should check the correctness of the argument above.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yes, your argument is correct. The relevant non-torsion class is the Euler class, which satisfies $e(V \oplus W) = e(V) e(W)$ when V, W are oriented bundles. Because all bundles over a sphere are oriented, and $H^i(S^{2n}; \Bbb Z) = 0$ for $0 < i < 2n$. If $M$ is oriented, then $e(M) = \chi(M) [M]$. So $TS^{2n}$ is indecomposable for all $n$.

Comment: @mme, thanks a lot.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thank you for your answer. I try to think about the homotopy groups.

Comment: This can be generalised, see my answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/270549/8103